# Xamarin PCL splash screen containing a web service call

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to have a Xamarin PCL ContentPage that displays a welcome message and then loads data from a web service. I have the web service working but the problem is that in the following example nothing is displayed while it takes time to work.

What is the general strategy for: displaying a wait-type Splash page, waiting for a long-running task to complete, and then continuing with the rest of the application (say a Main Menu page)?

Hopefully the strategy will work in the PCL project so that I don't have to try and write iOS and Android versions? I've tried to put code in various override methods, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
// The following is called from the "App : Application" class.
public class SplashScreen : ContentPage
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        Label lblWelcome = new Label { Text = "Hello. Please wait..." };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { lblWelcome }
        }

        //TODO: Have the device display the above content before the following continues...

        CallWebServiceToLoadParameters();

        //TODO: Move on to display the Main Menu
    }
}
```

Comment: moving CallWebServiceToLoadParameters(); to onApearing() should do the trick.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? Does it hang, give you an error? Does it reach the backend at all?

Comment: you need to separate your code , eg content from CallWebServiceToLoadParameters(); moving it to onAppearing() might not work, because if you do - CallWebServiceToLoadParameters() will be finished before you will show your splash screen. You might try to start CallWeb from different thread, and when it finished - move to new content page. But I would reccomend to look at implementing native splashes anyway.

Comment: Hi @GeraldVersluis. As I mentioned in the question, the web service call works just fine. The problem is that nothing is displayed on the Splash screen while it is working. I'm starting to realise that there is more to the Xamarin (PCL) Splash screen than I was hoping there'd be. I'm looking at http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=294 and https://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/User_Interface/Creating_a_Splash_Screen/

Comment: Hi @Yogesh. I tried the OnAppearing() trick, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This may do the trick:

```
public class SplashScreen : ContentPage
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        Label lblWelcome = new Label { Text = "Hello. Please wait..." };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { lblWelcome }
        }

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            //If awaitable
            var response = await CallWebServiceToLoadParameters();

            if(response{
                App.Current.MainPage = //Your main page.
            }
        });

    }
}
```

A little bit ugly, the correct way will be with a ViewModel for each page.